# PHP elseif not working.(Compare operators with integers)

Tags: php

```
function ageIssue($age){
    if ($age > 10) {
        echo "Age is greater than 10";
    } elseif ($age>20) {
        echo "Age is greater than 20";
    } elseif($age>30) {
        echo "Age is greater than 30";
    }else {
        echo "Enter valid age";
    }
 }

 ageIssue(32);
```

What is the fault of this code? I need the answer "Age is greater than 30" but But always it says "Age is greater than 10". Help please....

Comment: It's working fine. It does exactly what you told it to do. `if ($age > 10)` will be true for `20` and `30` as well (since they are also greater than `10`) so it will only execute the first `if` (as long as the value is greater than `10`)

Comment: First condtion succeeds, just [invert order of conditions](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4ALCNJK85JLMvPzFBLTUz2Li0tTNVSALM1qLgU0kJmmAJZSsFMwNtBUwFQAAqnJGfkKSo5AVZnFCulFqYklqUUKJRmJeUA9StYYWmoVUnOKU2Em2xmRYa4RPnMhxhqSYawhVmNBpuI1yjUPZEJZYk5mCihAsZnBhcZF5cNjwdhI0/r/fwA).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code logic is wrong. If you want to handle with `if else`, you must do it like this:

```
function ageIssue($age){
    if ($age > 30 && $age < 40) {
        echo "Age is greater than 30";
    } elseif ($age>20) {
        echo "Age is greater than 20";
    } elseif($age>10) {
        echo "Age is greater than 10";
    }else {
        echo "Enter valid age";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code executes up to the first true evaluation... break up your if statements to simplify your checks ... notice that I start with the least age.

#### Like below:

```
function ageIssue($age){

    $output = "Enter valid age";


    if ($age > 10) {
        $output = "Age is greater than 10";
    }

    if ($age > 20) {
        $output = "Age is greater than 20";
    } 

    if($age > 30) {
        $output = "Age is greater than 30";
    }

    echo $output;

 }

 ageIssue(32);
```

Comment: please share why I got a downvote ... it may be an honest mistake

Comment: Possibly down voted before edit, changed to up vote

Comment: All well. Thank you.
Happy codding!

Comment: I think because for example if age is i.e. 70 years, all IF statements are true;

Comment: My intention was to answer the question as asked and not add my own cases. Even then, if the age is 70, the response is the same and the complexity the same. I think your case would be valid if there are thousands/hundreds of comparisons to make.

Comment: In regard to a very large set results, I would solve the problem from a ```divide and conquer``` perspective

Answer (score 3):

You can start by testing value from **largest** to **smallest** ***if statements*** by

1. Calling a returning method

```
function ageIssue($age){
    if ($age > 70) {
        return "Age is greater than 70";
    } if ($age>50) {
        return "Age is greater than 50 but less than 70";
    } if($age>30) {
        return "Age is greater than 30 but less than 50";
    }if($age>10){
        return "Age is greater than 10 but less than 30.";
    }
    if($age>=1){
      return "Age is between 1 and 10.";
    } else {
        return "Invalid Age enter";
    } 
} 

echo ageIssue(32);
```

Comment: Then echo ageIssue(30);

Answer (score 1):

You need to start from the largest as you check the age

```
    function ageIssue($age)
{
    if ($age > 70) {
        return "Age is greater than 70";
    } elseif ($age > 50) {
        return "Age is greater than 50 but less than 70";
    } elseif ($age > 30) {
        return "Age is greater than 30 but less than 50";
    } elseif ($age > 10) {
        return "Age is greater than 10 but less than 30.";
    } elseif ($age >= 1) {
        return "Age is between 1 and 10.";
    } else {
        return "Invalid Age enter";
    }
}

echo ageIssue(32);
```